# One-to-many relationship to make a crud in spring-mvc. Not working when i'm posting?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have a one-to-many relationship with `SchoolField` and `SchoolYear` - so one school field can have one or more school year . 
Check the code 
`SchoolField` class

```
@Entity
public class SchoolField {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@NotEmpty
@NotNull
private String nameOfSchoolField;

@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "schoolField" , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<SchoolYear> schoolYears;

//getter and setter
```

`SchoolYear` class

```
@Entity
public class SchoolYear {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@NotNull
@NotEmpty
private String name;

@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "school_field" ,nullable = false)
private SchoolField schoolField;

//getter and setter
```

Repository of SchoolField .------

```
public interface SchoolFieldRepository extends              
JpaRepository<SchoolField,Long> {

public SchoolField findOneById(Long id);

public SchoolField findByNameOfSchoolField(String nameOfSchoolField);
}
```

Repository of SchoolYear ------

```
public interface SchoolYearRepository extends 
JpaRepository<SchoolYear,Long> {}
```

Services for SchoolField

```
 public interface SchoolYearServices {

 public SchoolYear addSchoolYear(SchoolYear schoolYears);

 public SchoolYear getSchoolYear(Long id);

 public List<SchoolYear> findAll();
  }
```

--I have a class Also SchoolYearImpl that implementes those methods using SchoolYearRepository with DI .

Also same with services of SchoolField

Now the controller of SchoolYear its with RestController Annotation

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping(value = "schoolyear")
 public class SchoolYearController {

 private SchoolYearServices schoolYearServices;


 @Autowired
public SchoolYearController(SchoolYearServices schoolYearServices) {
    this.schoolYearServices = schoolYearServices;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces =     
 MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
 consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<SchoolYear> saveSchoolYear(
@RequestBody SchoolYear   schoolYear ) {
    return new ResponseEntity<SchoolYear>
(schoolYearServices.addSchoolYear(schoolYear),HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

}

Now when i'm testing the rest services in Postman like this

I have in db one SchoolField : Name : Science Computer , Id : 1

> {"name" : "First Year" , "idOfSchoolField" : "1"}

Its showing me an error

`{
  "timestamp": 1481018084351,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
  "message": "Could not read document: Can not construct instance of com.org.model.SchoolField: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2')\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@2e228b24; line: 1, column: 43] (through reference chain: com.org.model.SchoolYear[\"schoolField\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.org.model.SchoolField: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2')\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@2e228b24; line: 1, column: 43] (through reference chain: com.org.model.SchoolYear[\"schoolField\"])",
  "path": "/schoolyear"
}`

I hope that you'll understand the problem .

Comment: try with `idOfSchoolField `, in your request param changed to `id`

Comment: I didn't understand you so well ?

Comment: your `SchoolYear` model has `id` as its variable and not `idOfSchoolField` that you are sending.